# Re ORA-01843: not a valid month error

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Query:

```
SELECT t3.e_id, t6.ei_id
FROM t3, t6
WHERE 
(TO_CHAR(t6.EI_Q17, 'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN 20160801 AND 20170731)
AND (t3.E_STATUS                = 'W')
AND (t3.E_START                 < '1/8/2016')
AND (t3.E_END                   > '31/7/2017')
```

but I get an error: `ORA-01843: not a valid month.`

Any idea how this can be resolved?

Thanks,
Ar

Answer (score 2):

Use standard date syntax and explicit `join`s:

```
SELECT t3.e_id, t6.ei_id
FROM t3 CROSS JOIN t6
WHERE t6.EI_Q17 BETWEEN DATE '2016-08-01' AND DATE '2017-07-31' AND
      t3.E_STATUS = 'W' AND
      t3.E_START < DATE '2016-08-01' AND
      t3.E_END > DATE '2017-07-31';
```

If you use `DATE` and ISO 8601 standard date formats, then you don't have to worry about the localization settings for date constants.  You also don't need to clutter up your queries with function calls.

Comment: Any idea how to decode this: AND (to_date('31-Jul-2017', 'DD-Mon-RRRR') - t3.E_START + 1  < 14)

Comment: Try `AND (DATE '2017-07-31' - t3.E_START + 1 < 14) `

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you must follow Gordon suggestion to Use standard date syntax and explicit joins. Secondly from your posted query it looks like the column `t6.EI_Q17` is `varchar` having `date`. In this case you need to cast it twice like below:

```
SELECT t3.e_id, t6.ei_id
  FROM t3 CROSS JOIN t6
 WHERE     TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (t6.EI_Q17, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN 20160801
                                                                       AND 20170731
       AND t3.E_STATUS = 'W'
       AND t3.E_START < TO_DATE ('2016-08-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
       AND t3.E_END > TO_DATE ('2017-07-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Simple demo:

```
SQL> select dt 
    from
    (select to_char(to_date('2017-06-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYYMMDD') dt from dual )
    where dt between 20170601 and 20170603 ;
```

Output:

```
20170601
```

Comment: I just checked column EI_Q17 shows datatype as date. So I don't need to cast it?

Comment: @ArunaRaghunam. So the current post worked for your or you are getting issues. incase of issue you can post the issue for further investigation

Comment: I am getting ORA-01843 not a valid month error when I plug the query in SSRS report

Comment: @ArunaRaghunam. Not sure how it works in SSRS but in oracle it should work fine. See a demo in answer